# Inconsistent CFBundleShortVersionString value

Tags: ios, xcode, build, xcode11

Using Xcode 11, on the first build after a "clean build folder" the value of `CFBundleShortVersionString` in Info.plist is properly overriden by a build phase script.

This way, we can override the generated Info.plist with a version number derived from a git tag, say `10.1.2`.

Here's the build script :

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Extract the latest tag
describe=`git describe --tags`

# Split by '-' char. The first part is the version number, the remaining part is the build number
version=`echo $describe | cut -d '-' -f1`
build=`echo $describe | cut -d '-' -f2`

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $version" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}" || exit 1
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $build" "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}" || exit 1
```

After the second build, the CFBundleShortVersionString value is taken from `MARKETING_VERSION` inside `.pbxproj` file. `MARKETING_VERSION` is a new property added in Xcode11 inside every scheme. Let's say that version number is 999.999.999

On the first debug run, the `CFBundleShortVersionString` would be 10.1.2. and then 999.999.999 after every succeeding builds. Like I said, if I clean the build folder, the version reverts back to the correct value of 10.1.2.

In Xcode 11 this happens both on the simulator and on a device and was working fine in Xcode 10 and previous versions.